# In an action method, how can I bind post data to a dynamic object?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, data-binding

I want to do this:

```
public ActionResult SaveStuff(dynamic vm) {

    StoreTheValue(vm.myvalue);

    return Content("Saved :)");
}
```

This doesn't work, MVC doesn't seem to want to create a dynamic object with properties that correspond to the post data of the request.

Now I know that the whole point of properly defined view models is to create strongly typed data structures and have MVC bind data into them, but given that I'm posting data from javascript using ajax it's not strongly typed data anyway, so I don't see that I'm loosing any maintainability by doing this, and it will save me time and effort creating view model classes.

Can anyone help suggest how I can bind post data to a dynamic object, posssibly using a custom model binder?

Comment: "will save me time and effort creating view model classes" doing something fastly isn´t always the best way to create a maintainable program. It´s not that hard to create DTO-objects that simply hold the information from your request and you should definitly put this afford. In particular when you already know what the objects of your requests look like - why not create a class for them? Just for saving some lines of code isnßt a good idea.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Sorry, but I'm not interested responses telling me what programming guidelines I should and shouldn't be following. I simply want to know how to bind post data to a dynamic object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to achieve this would be to use a custom model binder, assuming that you are posting Json to the action

```
public class DynamicBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel( ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext )
        {
            using( var streamReader = new StreamReader( controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream ) )
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< dynamic >( streamReader.ReadToEnd() );
            }
        }
    }
```

then in your action you can tell it, to use the custom binder

```
public ActionResult SaveStuff([ModelBinder(typeof(DynamicBinder))]dynamic vm) {

    StoreTheValue(vm.myvalue);

    return Content("Saved :)");
}
```

then post your json as such :

```
{
   "myvalue":{...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic` type and ajax request that you do with javascript ***is not corresponding***.

You always can create your strongly typed object properties on javascript side.

Anyway you can use `FormCollection` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult yourAction(FormCollection collection)
{
    StoreTheValue(Convert.ToString(collection["myvalue"]));

    return Content("Saved :)");
}
```

But I think it's better to think of a strongly typed way.

Comment: That doesn't bind to a dynamic object... not what I want. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BG100 i mean you can't do it with MVC binding. If you don't want to use strongly typed `ViewModel` the only chouse is `FormCollection`

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible...? What about using a custom model binder?

Comment: @BG100 you can try. but it's not worth it. If you need everything dynamic just use js on server side ;) nodeJs - is your best friend. You don't need any MVC with it's model binding at all